# Css equivalent of :eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im looking for a way to replace an jquery path selector to a valid css selector.

I got my jquery selector like that

```
div>div:eq(0)>span>span:eq(3)>a>span { background-image:url('../bigData.png'); }
```

And i need something that i can write to my css file to get the style renderer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I think you can opt for [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)

```
div>div:nth-of-type(1)>span>span:nth-of-type(4)>a>span { background-image:url('../bigData.png'); }
```

But there is no real equal method in css for jquery [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)